# OnActivityResult from android.app.Fragment not returning

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have been searching for days on this problem and found nothing
the problem is when i call the `onActivityResult()` from a fragment trying to get image from the gallery
the application just closes after i pick the photo
i tried to 
1- call `super.onActivityResult`
2- `this.onActivityResult`
3- implementing the `onActivityResult` in my activity
i hardly tried every single solution google and stackoverflow introduced to me
please help me
this is my code

```
package com.optimalsolutionjo.schools.app.fragments;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.optimalsolutionjo.schools.app.activities.R;

public class StudentProfileFragment extends Fragment {
    private View generalView;
    private Context context;
    private ImageView studentPic;
    private String selectedImagePath;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        generalView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.student_profile, container,
                false);
        context = generalView.getContext();
        studentPic = (ImageView) generalView.findViewById(R.id.studentPic);
        studentPic.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(
                        Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), 1);
            }
        });
        return generalView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                System.out.println("Image Path : " + selectedImagePath);
                studentPic.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null,
                null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }
}
```

i really tried putting onActivityResult everywhere and in every possible way
Thanks in advance

Comment: what happen with you ? did it crash or just you can't do it?

Comment: it just do nothing just finishes the program
there is no log cat for anything too

Comment: you mean it dosen't even open gallery to pick image ?

Comment: it opens the gallery but after selecting the image my application is not there
just like i have called finish() after startActivityForResult
but i did not do that

Comment: i tried this code on Activity it works like a charm but not in Fragment

Comment: your look nice , did you get any thing "Image Path : " , i want make sure onActivityResult called  , if you can please remove this part until we finish (selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);)

Comment: add Log.d in the beginning of onActivityResult

Comment: the add log.d wont work because the activity is killed its never opened again 
that's the problem
and for the path no i am not because my app just quits after selecting image